# only apply cdkDragHandle to the header in child component

Tags: angular, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I want the drag component present as a popup floating on the screen, and user only can move the popup by dragging the header. However, the `cdkDrag` is applied on the parent component. So it can still moved by dragging outside the header.

app.component.ts

```
<app-popup
    cdkDrag
    cdkDragBoundary=".body-container"
    [cdkDragFreeDragPosition]="{ x: -10, y: 0 }"
    [style.width]="'150px'"
    [style.height]="'150px'"
  >
  </app-popup>
```

app.component.css

```
app-popup {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

popup.component.ts

```
<app-item></app-item>
```

item.component.ts

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-header">Drag Here !</div>
  <div class="item-content">Please no drag by here.</div>
</div>
```

item.component.css

```
.item-header {
  cursor: move;
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Please tell me how to only apply the `cdkDragHandle` to the header. Thank you.

[StackBlitz - cdkDrag](https://stackblitz.com/edit/neverland-cdkdraghandle?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cdkDragHandle` is the directive designed for these kind of situations
https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDragHandle

The slight problem here is that is needs to be applied to a direct descendant of the draggable element that has `cdkDrag`.
To achieve this the dragged header could be pass through as the content of popover down to the parent.

[Updated stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/neverland-cdkdraghandle-raewjt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

The above fix does not have the styles applied, but this could be resolved by having a separate component for the header.